# Can you reverse-generate the RSA/AES key if you have the decrypted and encrypted version of the same string? (JS client-side crypto)

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptojs

Trying to do some client-side encryption for some configuration credentials (nothing sensitive) in angular. But if I import the module with the wrong credentials, everything will crash.

So I'm thinking before-hand if I could test out with a small string if the encryption key is correct or wrong, before deciding to load the module.

This would require me to have in my client code a decrypted and encrypted version of the same string which leads to me trying to find out if it is possible for someone to use that.

Comment: Not sure why you need an encypted & decrypted version of the string, why not just send an encrypted message, like a magic string, if the decrypted string is equal to the magic string, this would mean the credentials are correct.

Comment: @Keith because all this code will have to run client side without any authentication or captchas. There's nothing being sent client-server and I wouldn't want to involve a server in this particular app.

There's a very good business reason to go this route for this specific case.

Comment: Same thing applies, client or server.   I assume your protecting some sort of data?..  inside you data you store a magic value, you encrypt / decrypt with user password, if inside your data the magic value is correct, your fine otherwise it's wrong and you can abort.

Comment: @Keith ah, I understand what you mean! So this is more specific with angular's lazy loaded module. I'm protecting the firebase project key + url which needs to be retrieved from localstorage when the module is loaded. 

If the key/value is incorrect, there is no way to prevent the module from loading. The whole app will crash and the user will have to manually refresh the page to try again, which is not a great experience.

I could however encrypt a parsed JS object and do a comparison with an extra key on that object.

Comment: Yes, that should be fine.  You might think doing something like this opens up a brute force attack,.  Well yes it does, and it would anyway if everything is client side.  But modern encryption is very good these days, use a very strong RSA, and a very strong password it would take even a super computer a very long time to crack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any modern professional-grade algorithm? No.
This is a security vulnerability (known-plaintext or "crib" attack), it has been a concern since the Enigma days and, of course, a primary design goal for asymmetric encryption which followed.

AES, for example, iterates the key over the plaintext a many times, to the point where a reverse function cannot be calculated.
The remaining method for the attacker is to run keys in a brute-force way. If the plaintext string is shorter than the key, than we can throw the idea out at this point, as there is not enough information.
If the string is as long as the key, and the key is of professional length, this brute force will be an "all computing power by the end of the universe" problem.

Comment: Thank you, so for all intents and purposes I should be fine. Haven't looked into the 'crib attack' term before this so I'll be able to check for that against any algorhitm I'll be using. I'll mark your answer as correct when stackoverflow allows me!

Comment: I am trying to find an example of how they protect against it

Comment: AES doesn't suffer from crib attacks.  So the OP should be fine.  More info here -> https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/why-is-aes-resistant-to-known-plaintext-attacks